# SELECT COUNT(a.id) AS id... => Result array is empty! [PHP, MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm having trouble with some PHP since yesterday, looked through the web and had the stupid feeling that I'm missing something important.

Using `mysql_fetch_object` usually, tried it with `mysql_fetch_array` though (did not help). Here's the part of the code which gives me an headache:

```
public static function get_datacenter_by_id($id) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(rack.id) AS Racks, COUNT(device.id) AS Devices, COUNT(card.id) AS Cards, COUNT(port.id) AS Ports 
          FROM datacenter, rack, device, card, port, location, building 
          WHERE location.id = building.location_id AND
          building.id = datacenter.building_id AND
          datacenter.id = '.$id.' AND
          rack.id = device.rack_id AND
          device.id = card.device_id AND
          (card.id = port.card_id1 OR
          card.id = port.card_id2)") or die ("Error in query: ".mysql_error());

$array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $array[] = array($row->Racks, $row->Devices, $row->Cards, $row->Ports);                     
}

return $array;
}
```

$array is used in another .php file, but using `print_r $array` already shows you, that the array stays `empty (0)`. I'm quite sure that the error appears in this block of code, could "**`COUNT (x) AS y`**" be at fault?

PS: The MySQL Query works, tested it via Workbench before. I'd appreciate some good adivce! :-)

Have a nice day!

Comment: Start with error handling and actual debugging. What does `var_dump($result)` give? How many rows are returned from the database query (yes I already know that you expect more than 0 rows, but please share with us how many rows exactly are returned).

Comment: There are 12 units of test data in the DB!

Comment: This query, assuming that it compiles, will always return exactly one record no matter what. What does it return in the workbench?

Comment: Result of var_dump($result):
array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "0" [3]=> string(1) "0" } }

Racks  Devices Cards  Ports
12  12  12  12

Comment: Well the db contains data, I believe you. But how is that related to your question? We already know that you expect data, but actually there is no data. Now you have to deal with the difference between your expectation and the reality. That's all this is about.

Comment: "0" does not mean it's empty?
Well, I expect that $row contains a number; the number of rows which COUNT() counted; am I on the wrong boat here?!

Comment: Add `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your script. Then read through all the warnings and errors and fix them.

Comment: `array(1)` means that it's not. It contains exactly one element as it should. Could you please post what did you expect the query to return?

Comment: try `var_dump($row)` now as well.

Comment: using foreach($array as $var) {
    echo $array[0];
}

Comment: With your query, all four fields are guaranteed to have the same value. Please post what did you expect the query to return (not `$row`, not anything else in `PHP`, but the query itself, as if you had run it in the client).

Comment: SELECT COUNT(rack.id) AS Racks, COUNT(device.id) AS Devices, COUNT(card.id) AS Cards, COUNT(port.id) AS Ports 
       FROM datacenter, rack, device, card, port, location, building 
       WHERE location.id = building.location_id AND
       building.id = datacenter.building_id AND
       datacenter.id = '1' AND
       rack.id = device.rack_id AND
       device.id = card.device_id AND
       (card.id = port.card_id1 OR
       card.id = port.card_id2)

Comment: There is no need to reposting the query itself. What did you expect it to return?

Comment: I expected a number in each row!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this as simple as:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(rack.id) AS Racks, COUNT(device.id) AS Devices,     COUNT(card.id) AS Cards, COUNT(port.id) AS Ports 
      FROM datacenter, rack, device, card, port, location, building 
      WHERE location.id = building.location_id AND
      building.id = datacenter.building_id AND
      datacenter.id = '" . $id . "' AND
      rack.id = device.rack_id AND
      device.id = card.device_id AND
      (card.id = port.card_id1 OR
      card.id = port.card_id2)") or die ("Error in query: ".mysql_error());
```

Note the modification from '.$id.' to '" . $id . "'.  Your query is looking for a data centre ID of '.$id.'.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using it like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
$array[] = array($row->Racks, $row->Devices, $row->Cards, $row->Ports);                     
}
```

You should do this

```
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result)
$array[] = $row->Racks;
$array[] = $row->Devices;
$array[] = $row->Cards;
```

Because you are fetching 1 record and using it in while is causing problem

Comment: No, that was not the problem; actually by changing it to your proposal, I got more difficult results.

Still a huge thanks for trying and answering, I really appreciate it!